# PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant idq - assumed 'idq'

Tags: php

Im getting this php notice , and my program works perfectly.
here is my code :

```
    $data =  file_get_contents('php://input');
    $P = isset(json_decode($data)->E->EP->P) ? json_decode($data)->E->EP->P : '0';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $P; $i++) {
        ${idq.$i} = isset(json_decode($data)->E->EP->{idq.$i}) ? json_decode($data)->E->EP->{idq.$i} : '0';
           }
echo ${idq.$i};
```

should i fix or suppress the error with handling?

Comment: What stops you from correcting it?

Comment: `idq` is unknown... What is that? Might be `{'idq'.$i}` ?

Comment: php notices are not very important and doesnt kill the process , but you better fix it

Comment: @CORRUPT thanks , that was the problem , i missed the qoute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want your variables to be named `$idq1`, `$idq2`, `$idq3` etc:

They're currently being considered as constants. If you want them in your variables, you need wrap your `idq` constant in quotes:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $P; $i++) {
    ${'idq'.$i} = isset(json_decode($data)->E->EP->{'idq'.$i}) ? json_decode($data)->E->EP->{'idq'.$i} : '0';
}

echo ${'idq'.$i};
```

But ternary statements make your code a bit ugly (at least, in this case). But, this looks a lot more cleaner, IMO:

```
$data =  file_get_contents('php://input');

if(isset(json_decode($data)->E->EP->P)) {
    $P = json_decode($data)->E->EP->P;
}
else {
    $P = '0';
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $P; $i++) {

    if(isset(json_decode($data)->E->EP->{'idq'.$i}) ) {
        ${'idq'.$i} = json_decode($data)->E->EP->{'idq'.$i};
    }
    else {
        ${'idq'.$i} = '0';
    }

}
```

Also, to answer your final, question:

> should i fix or suppress the error with handling?

Nope. Never. You should always find and fix the error instead of suppressing it.

Answer (score 1):

Always fix your errors, suppressing is not the solution for anything, it's just a bomb waiting to go off sometime...